# Array changing after while

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code which receives as an input an unlimited amount of names, and prints how many were entered and the names. However, it seems that after the `while` loop is finished each place in the array of strings is "QUIT" which is the end condition of the `while` loop. I would appreciate if someone could see what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() 
{
      char Input_String[50]="bla";
      printf("Please enter list of names:"); 
      char** InputArr=(char**)malloc(1*sizeof(char**)); 
      int count=1; 
      fgets(Input_String,50,stdin); 
      if(strcmp(Input_String,"QUIT\n")) 
          InputArr[0]=Input_String; 
      printf("%s",InputArr[0]);    
      while(strcmp(Input_String,"QUIT\n")) 
      {                
          fgets(Input_String,50,stdin); 
          if(strcmp(Input_String,"QUIT\n")!=0) 
          { 
               count++; 
               InputArr= (char**)realloc(InputArr,(count)*sizeof(char*));                 
               InputArr[count-1]=Input_String; 
               printf("%s",InputArr[count-1]); 
          }
      }
      printf("There are %d names:\n",count); 
      int i; 
      for(i=0;i<count;i++) 
      {
          printf("%s",InputArr[i]);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

In this line

```
InputArr[count-1]=Input_String;
```

You are writing the address of that string into every array element. So when you have finished, they all point to the last message you typed, which was `QUIT`.

I suggest

```
InputArr[count-1]=strdup(Input_String);
```

but please remember to `free` the memory allocated by `strdup` later.